# can't copy .sqlite file in documents directory

Tags: sqlite, ios5

I'm not able to copy this sqlite file in documents directory: nothing has been copied.... please anyone knows what I'm I missing? Thank you!

```c
BOOL success;
//documents path
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"verbi2.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if (success) return;
//bundle path
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"verbi2.sqlite"];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:nil];
```

I've solved creating a new .sqlite file (verbi5.sqlite); probably something was corrupted.